# OrientDB can't get edges with direction.OUT

Tags: java, graph, orientdb

I am trying to identify an edge having the start vertex and end vertex.

For this purpose I'm calling:

```
vertexStart.getEdges(Direction.OUT, relationshipId)
```

which seems to be always empty.

Getting the incoming edges seems to work but I need both.

```
vertexStart.getEdges(Direction.IN, relationshipId)
```

relationshipId is the label of the edge.

```
Iterable<Vertex> startNodes = this.getVertexList(storage.getStartNode(), graph);
            Iterable<Vertex> endNodes = this.getVertexList(storage.getEndNode(), graph);

            for (Vertex startNode : startNodes)
            {
                for (Vertex endNode : endNodes)
                {
                    String edgeClass = "class:" + storage.getId();
                    Edge edge = startNode.addEdge(edgeClass, endNode);

                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : storage.getProperties().entrySet())
                    {
                        edge.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    }
                    edge.setProperty(Constants.TAG_HASH, HashCreator.sha1FromRelationship(storage));
                    edge.setProperty(Constants.TAG_SNAPSHOT_ID, snapshotId);
                }
            }
            graph.commit();
```

Is used to create the structure.

Comment: What version of orientdb are you using  ?

Comment: compile group: 'com.orientechnologies', name: 'orientdb-graphdb', version: '2.2.11'

Comment: @AlessandroRota do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that your vertices have outcoming edges ?
Is it possible that they have only incoming edges?

Comment: Following the code above it should be impossible to create an edge without both vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem and it worked in my case.
I created this graph

[image]

The vertex #10:0 had one edge in input and one edge in output.

I used this code.

```
Vertex v = g.getVertex("#10:0");

System.out.println("OUT");
Iterable<Edge> itOut=v.getEdges(Direction.OUT, "E");
for(Edge e:itOut){
    System.out.println(e.getId());
}

System.out.println("IN");
Iterable<Edge> itIn=v.getEdges(Direction.IN, "E");
for(Edge e:itIn){
    System.out.println(e.getId());
}
```

and I got

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Might there be something wrong with the way I store the edges?
I will update the main post with the code.